# Hotkeys in Lubuntu 14.10

Tags: unity, lubuntu, shortcut-keys, 14.10

I installed Lubuntu 14.10 yesterday (previously I used Ubuntu) and I want to activate the some usefule hotkeys that Ubuntu has.

In Ubuntu, for instance, you can move opened programs on the right side of the desktop by using the keyboard with the hotkey:

```
ctrl + SUPER + right_arrow
```

In Lubuntu, it is not possible, or, at least, it isn't just after the installation.

Also installing unity tweak tool it does not work.

How can I do that?

Comment: Just FYI, Unity tweak will have no effect on LXDE (Lubuntu's desktop environment) - which is not related at all to Unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page has an explanation on how to setup shortcuts [Lubuntu/Keboard](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard)

Relevant section says:

> There is no automatic way to create new keyboard shortcuts or hotkeys
>   in lubuntu. You will either have to edit Lubuntu's openbox
>   configuration file (~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml) and edit, or
>   alternatively install xbindkeys.
>
> Obkey will edit the keyboard parts of your Openbox configuration file
>   for you. Download the .tar.gz and unarchive it. After unpacking the
>   tar.gz, open a command line in the new folder and run obkey like this:
>   ./obkey ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml  Hint: back up your config
>   file. After saving the config file, you will need to run this command
>   to have openbox use the changed config: openbox --reconfigure
>
> For more information on the syntax of the configuration file, please
>   check out the official Openbox documentation on bindings. Note that
>   Super_R and Super_L are the two "Windows" keys when you just want to
>   use those keys. If you want to couple them with something else, use W-
>   plus whatever key you want to use.